# How to partial sync Dropbox contents to my device?

Tags: dropbox

Is it possible to sync only *some* folders of Dropbox?

I have 5GB+ files on Dropbox cloud, but only want a few folders to be synced to my Galaxy Tab 7.7.

Comment: When were you able to do full sync with official Dropbox app??

Comment: Like Sachin implied: as far as I know, the Dropbox app doesn't automatically sync the contents of any files except those that you mark as being a "favorite".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there's a way. It's called [Foldersync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full). It allows you to set up folder pairs to sync and the full version even allows you to sync on changes. It also supports several other cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different account for the phone, and just share the folders you want to sync to the phone account.

15 Oct

Saw a down-vote, so perhaps it was not clear.
It is quite easy to share files between Dropbox accounts.

Of course this is only relevant if you use a DropBox app that doesn't allow selective syncing.
(There are many DropBox apps)

Answer (score 0):

I have a Galaxy Tablet (GT-N8013). In the dropbox application, you can 'star' specific files or folders to download to your device. This is useful if your tablet will be offline (no wifi) for a period of time. Changes that you make to the document on the tablet will be saved to your dropbox folder,and when you re-connect to the internet will become available almost immediately.

If you are going to be somewhere that has wifi, the dropbox folder allows you to open the documents from dropbox, use them, make changes or notes, and save back to dropbox. This makes it very easy to take documents to meetings via the tablet using the dropbox folder.

Answer (score 0):

In the Dropbox app, you can press and hold a file, then choose "Favorite". This will store it locally and make it available for offline access.

The option is not available for folders, so if you want access to a new file you'll need to sync, then mark each new file for download.

Jeepers, though, they didn't make this easy to find!!