# Can I keep all of my Dropbox data on SD card?

Tags: applications, dropbox

Is there any way to configure the Dropbox app so that all Dropbox files, now and future, are available offline on the SD card?

Comment: There isn't any way. You can do that by using apps that sync Dropbox to external SD

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of such an app, or should I ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?  My idea, though, is that all of my DropBox stuff is available offline, and I think that you have to do that on a per file basis, so it may not be easy, or even possible

Comment: I use this [paid app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync) which works very well. Free version allows only sync of selected folder and pro entire Dropbox with a host of useful options. If you want give it a try and let me know

Comment: Alas see this. Your question is probably a dupe of this and am going to vote for closing. https://android.stackexchange.com/q/26728/131553

Comment: I haven't tried folder sync though so not sure if it backs up to SD card. If it doesn't, please clarify so that your question is not closed

Comment: I don't want to "partially" synch. I want to have my complete DropBox files available off line. Not just current files, but any added in future. Perhaps I ought to ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Your choice. But the app I linked does completely back up to internal or SD. Only drawback is paid app. I use it a lot. Files added are automatically synced

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that DropBox does not seem to make files available offline unless you manually fetch them, so I would need an app to do that for me - or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81988/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-mawg).

Comment: Check this out.. https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-files-folders/How-to-transfer-Dropbox-files-to-a-USB-or-Disk/td-p/91079

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can**

- Specifically, making a file available offline:
- Adds the file to your Offline view for easy access (like a bookmark)
- Saves the file to your Android device for offline viewing within
  Dropbox
- Attempts to keep the file as up-to-date as possible and gives you the
  option to update the file manually
- Ensures that any changes you make to the file while offline will be
  synced to your Dropbox account once you have a connection again

Comment: I don't want to make ***a*** file offline. I want to make ***all*** of my DropBox files available offline. Both those which I have today and those which I add in future, and I do not want to have to do it manually for each file.

Comment: There was an an unofficial app that did just that. Search the Play Store. It is not allowed to give software recommendations here.